# Cannot complete migration on LAMP

Tags: migration, localhost, apache

I have a WordPress site with LAMP. Since I moved to a new apartment the site does not display well anymore, and I cannot access its dashboard through `http://my-wp-site.com/wp-admin`.

**Note 1:** I set up my Apache server to host two websites, my personal one (the primary site, which **does not** use wordpress) and the WordPress site that’s the object of this question.

**Note 2:**  have bought separate domains for each site. In the old place I had a fixed public IP, so both domains pointed to that IP, which would then resolve to either the primary site or WP site according to their respective `ServerName`.
After I moved to the new place I had to set up a Dynamic DNS service. Now both domains points to that service’s url (`http://mydnsdomain.ddns.com`). Users can still access the website through each site domain address, which remained `http://my-primary-site.com` and `http://my-wp-site.com`.
**Since I changed the access point from my the old fixed public IP to the dynamic dns address, I understand this is a case of migrating the WordPress site**.

**Note 3:** I have backed up my website through UpdadraftPlus and am trying to restore from that backup.

**WHAT I DID**

1. I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-18-04) to do a clean install of wordpress.
2. I then created a news MySQL database for the new installation.
3. Once the set up was done, I installed the UpdadraftPlus plug-in, and uploaded the backup files. I restored each component one by one: uploads, themes, plugins, others and database. All but the last one work fine.
4. When I try to restore the database I get this warning message:

> "The website address in the backup set (http://my-wp-site.com) is slightly different from that of the site now (http://www.my-wp-site.com). This is not expected to be a problem for restoring the site, as long as visits to the former address still reach the site"

I ignored the warning because both those addresses point to the ddns, which I thought would re-route the request to the new address, as it did before restoring the database.

After restoring the database, I get another warning saying that `"The database table needs to be repaired"`. I follow the instructions and go through the repair process – according to which everything went fine.

However, once that is done the website (`http://my-wp-site.com`) looks messed up, and the admin dashboard (`http://my-wp-site.com/wp-admin`) is not accessible: `"Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."`

I wondered if this was due to the dynamic DNS interfering, but before I restored the database everything worked.

[This article](https://homeschoolrealm.com/how-to-migrate-a-wordpress-site-manually-for-free-using-updraftplus/) suggests to use the better search replace plug-in to solve the problem, but I cannot access my dashboard.

I thought about two options:

1. Avoid creating a new database during the installation and set the website to the same `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD` and `DB_HOST` as before. (Sounds risky.)
2. Do the `better search replace` procedure before restoring the database.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I'd guess it's the Apache VirtualHost config. Is the www version definitely configured as a virtual host?

Comment: This is how the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my-wp-site.conf` file is set: `ServerName mydnsdomain.ddns.com | ServerAlias www.my-wp-site.com | ServerAlias my-wp-site.com`. (the "|" symbol represents a line break, and is not present in the file) Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by adding these two lines to `/var/www/my-wp-site.com/public_html/wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

Comment: OK, so you just had the two URLs configured wrong in settings, general? Glad you got it working, but I'm not sure that explains the admin site not working.